# getMonth throws wrong month (81) - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get the month of a date, but it keeps showing me this: `"2018-81-26 07:00"`.. This is my function that I use for setting the date that I need:

```
selectStartTime(time) {
      this.selectedTime = '' + time.time + ' ' + time.period;

      var date = new Date(this.start_at); // this shows good date: 
      //Wed Sep 26 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

      var period = time.period;
      var hours = '';

// error occurs here:
      var year = date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth()+1 + '-' + date.getDate();
// year: 2018-81-26 07:00



      if (period === 'PM') {
          hours = '' + (time.value + 12) + ':00';
          this.campaignModel.starts_at = year + ' ' + hours;
      } else {
          hours = time.time;
          this.campaignModel.starts_at = year + ' ' + hours;
      }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `date.getMonth()` returns 8 (september), you're in a string context so when you do `+1` it appends 1 to the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just change below code

```
var year = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + date.getDate();
```

Comment: Or `year = date.toISOString().slice(0,10)`

Answer (score 4):

It's actually because of the +1

```
var year = date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth()+1 + '-' + date.getDate();
```

It gets date.getMonth which is equal to 8, but since you're doing +1 and the var is treated as a string, instead of adding one, it adds the number 1 at the end, which makes it 81

If for whatever reason you need the +1, you should declare it before hand like

```
var month = year.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear() + '-' + month+ '-' + date.getDate();
```

Or do like other answers did correctly as well

```
var year = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + date.getDate();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
var year = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + date.getDate();
```

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend you to use a popular library for handling/dealing with date and time 
https://momentjs.com/

```
var d = moment(scope.date);
d.month(); // 1
d.format('ddd MMM DD YYYY'); // 'Mon Feb 01 2016
```

Comment: Please don't recommend adding libraries when it's not necessary.

Answer (score -2):

today im using Momentjs its better for many purposes

https://momentjs.com/

you can format dates and retrieve any part of that like this

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // September 25th 2018, 10:02:25 am
moment().format('dddd');                    // Tuesday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Sep 25th 18
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2018 escaped 2018
moment().format();                          // 2018-09-25T10:02:48-03:00
```